# Django Shell update objects value

Tags: django, django-models, django-shell

I want to increase the prices by 30% in django shell.

models.py:

```
price = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

shell:

```
from product.models import Product
Product.objects.all().update(price=price*1.3)
```

error:

```
NameError: name 'price' is not defined
```

Comment: Have you run the migrations after adding the `price = models.FloatField(null=True)` line to your model ?

Comment: Of course running migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an F expression to reference the field in the database
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

```
from django.db.models import F
from product.models import Product
Product.objects.all().update(price=F('price')*1.3)
```